# cs50 pset5 Have too many misspelled words

Tags: c, hashtable, cs50

This is a pset of cs50 course. The task is loading words into an array of linked lists (hashtable) and then checking texts to see if the words are misspelled or not. Check() function seems suspicious but can not figure out why. Any help is appreciated. (Comparison of the words is case-insensitive.)

MY OUTPUT:

```
WORDS MISSPELLED:     5440(TOO MUCH)
WORDS IN DICTIONARY:  143091
WORDS IN TEXT:        17756
TIME IN load:         0.02
TIME IN check:        0.06
TIME IN size:         0.00
TIME IN unload:       0.01
TIME IN TOTAL:        0.09
```

CLASS SOLUTION:

```
WORDS MISSPELLED:     955
WORDS IN DICTIONARY:  143091
WORDS IN TEXT:        17756
TIME IN load:         0.04
TIME IN check:        0.01
TIME IN size:         0.00
TIME IN unload:       0.02
TIME IN TOTAL:        0.07
```

```
// Implements a dictionary's functionality

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "dictionary.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>

int n = 0;


// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

// Number of buckets in hash table
const unsigned int N = 5000;

// Hash table
node *table[N];

// Returns true if word is in dictionary else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    int index = hash(word);

    if (table[index] == NULL)//nothing loaded here (no link to the head)
    {
        return false;
    }

    node *iter = table[index];//iterator pointer to jump on linked list = root

    while (iter != NULL )// it could not find the word, keep searching
    {
        if (strcasecmp(iter -> word, word))
        {
            iter = iter ->next;
        }

        else if (!strcasecmp(iter -> word, word))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Hashes word to a number
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    //between 0 N - 1 N = 5000
    int count = strlen(word);

    int sum = 0;

    for ( int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        sum += (int)word[i];
    }

    return round(sum % 5000);
}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{

    char wordx[LENGTH+1];

    FILE *f = fopen(dictionary, "r");//opens the dictionary for reading

    for (int i = 0; i < N ; i++)//appending all the nuls to the table
    {
        table[i] = NULL;
    }

    while (f == NULL)
    {
        printf("File could not opened.");//Checking file
        return false;
    }
    while (fscanf(f, "%s", wordx) != EOF )//Until coming to the end of the file
    {
        node* p = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));//creating a new node for each word

        if (p == NULL)
        {
            printf("Memory could not allocated.");
            return false;
        }

        strcpy(p -> word, wordx);//putting buffers word in to the node

        int numindex = hash(wordx);

        memset(wordx,0,LENGTH);//cleaning the buffer

        node* iter = table[numindex]; //iterator pointer = root of the hash table

        if (table[numindex] == NULL)//first appending to the hash table
        {

            table[numindex] = p; //appending "hashed" index function to the START of linked list

            p -> next = NULL; // appended function now points null

            n++;
        }
        else
        {

        table[numindex] = p;//head pointing new node

        p-> next = iter;//new node pointing to the old node

        n++;
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
    return true;
}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
     return n ;
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful else false
bool unload(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        node* iterf; //forward iteration
        node* iterb; //pointer that stays behind of iterf

        iterf = table[i];
        iterb = iterf;
        while (iterb != NULL)
        {
            iterf = iterb -> next;
            free(iterb);
            iterb = iterf;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Note: the same word will hash differently if the case is different. You can convert to lower case when hashing: `sum += tolower(word[i]);`

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  Using: `gcc -ggdb -c -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` results in 2 error messages,   complaints about a 'implicit declaration' of function:  `hash()` and lots of complaints about comparisons between signed and unsigned numbers.  I.E. the posted code doesn't compile, so it has never been executed.  Please post your actual code

Comment: regarding: `node *table[N];` at file scope results in the error message: *untitled1.c:24:7: error: variably modified ‘table’ at file scope*

Comment: regarding: `const unsigned int N = 5000;`  this is something used in C++, and does not work the same in C.  Suggest using: `#define N 5000`

Comment: regarding: function: `unsigned int hash(const char *word)`  This function is referenced BEFORE it is defined.  Therefore, the compiler will use the default parameter and return type of `int`, which results in an incorrect code generation

Comment: OT: regarding: `FILE *f = fopen(dictionary, "r");`  Always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: OT: regarding: `node* p = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));`  1) in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code and is error prone.  Suggest removing that cast.

Comment: regarding: `printf("Memory could not allocated.");`  1) Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  2) when the error is from a C library function, should also output to `stderr`, the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  The function: `perror()` is made to handle both outputs.

Comment: Where is the `main()` function?  functions: `load()` and `unload()` are never called.

Comment: regarding: `typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;`  1) for flexibility, best to separate the struct definition from the `typedef` for that definition  2)  the macro: `LENGTH` is never defined

Comment: regarding: `while (fscanf(f, "%s", wordx) != EOF )`  this has no limit on the length of a word.  Therefore, any entry in the file: `dictionary.txt` could result in overflowing the input buffer.  The result is undefined behavior and could result in a seg fault event.  Suggest using a MAX CHARACTERS modifier on the `%s` input format conversion specifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer, because `%s` always appends a NUL byte to the input.

Comment: regarding; `for (int i = 0; i < N ; i++)//appending all the nuls to the table
    {
        table[i] = NULL;
    }`  this code block is not necessary as the array `table[]` is in file space, which is always initialized to all `0x00`

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.

Comment: regarding: `while (fscanf(f, "%s", wordx) != EOF )`  this is not a good way to make the comparison.  What if the call to `fscanf()` failed to read a word, but it is not the end of the file?   Suggest: `while ( fscanf( f, "%s", wordx ) == 1 )`

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.  Be sure to include a (very) few lines from the `dictionary.txt` file

Answer (score 0):

This is my actual code and in the cs50 IDE which is where we develop the code, this page used as a heather file to another file. So it may not work on your compile on its own. Main function and everything is in one of the other files. But I found the problem. It is the hash function really `sum += tolower(word[i]);` solved my problem. @user3629249 and @Johnny Mopp Thanks bot of you for the help. Also your warnings about the design of the code was very helpful thanks for that too @user3629249. :)